# AWS auth seesion not keeping alive when we close the android application

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-userpools

I'm using AWS Amplify SDK for Cognito integration. Actually, I successfully integrated user sign in and sign up flows based on the documentation available [here](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/getting-started/q/platform/android). However, after the successful login if we restart the app the user session is not persisting. `Amplify.Auth.fetchAuthSession()` always returns `isSignedIn` as `false`. I have no idea where I'm making a problem. Please find the 'sign in' snippet below.

```
fun onSingIn(view: View) {
    Amplify.Auth.signIn(
            email.value,
            password.value,
            { result ->
                Log.i(TAG, if (result.isSignInComplete) "Sign in succeeded" else "Sign in not complete")

                if (result.isSignInComplete) {
                    view.context.let {
                        it.startActivity(Intent(it, FeedActivity::class.java))
                        signInStatus.postValue(true)
                    }
                }

            },
            { error ->
                view.context.let {
                    var message = it.getString(R.string.something_went_wrong)
                    when (error.cause) {
                        is UserNotConfirmedException ->{
                            email.value?.let {emailAddress ->
                                val direction =LoginFragmentDirections
                                        .actionLoginFragmentToEmailVerificationCodeFragment(emailAddress)
                                view.findNavController().navigate(direction)
                            }
                        }
                        is UserNotFoundException ->
                            message = it.getString(R.string.credentilas_incorrect)
                        else->
                            viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { it.showToast(message) }
                    }
                    Log.e(TAG, error.toString())
                }

            }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue. The problem was related user pool app client settings configurations. ***I haven't checked identity providers inside app client settings***. After choosing 'Cognito User Pool' as an identity provider the login session stayed alive without any issues. Hope this answer will help someone facing a similar issue.